# Unable to get data again from network once it has come from cache

Tags: android, caching, retrofit

I am trying to cache my network request data. I have specified its max-age=60. Data should come from cache till 60 seconds. But the problem is that i am getting data everytime from cache and not able to send network request again. I want that the data should come from network once the time has expired i.e. 60 seconds..Below is my code i am using retrofit to cache requests :

```
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(new Cache(MyApp.getInstance().getCacheDir(), 5 * 1024 * 1024))
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    if (hasNetwork(MyApp.getInstance()))
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + 60).build();
                    else
                        request = request.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7).build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            })
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .baseUrl("https://reqres.in")
            .build();
```

Comment: does your `hasNetwork()` function running correct? can you share it

Comment: yes its running correct